# Create task in macOS alwise return kern error

Tags: macos-catalina

This is my code:

```
    task_t                  child;
    kern_return_t           kr;
    ledger_t                ledgers = (ledger_t)0;
    boolean_t               inheret = FALSE;
    ledger_array_t          ledger_array = &ledgers;
    mach_msg_type_number_t  count = 1;


    kr = task_create(mach_task_self(), ledger_array, count, inheret, &child);
    if ( kr != KERN_SUCCESS)
    {
            printf("We failed getting the task\n");
            mach_error("task created: ", kr);
            exit(1);
    }
```

I always get: "task created:  (os/kern) failure" (I tried to run this as normal use and as root - always get the error).
What do I do rung?